# Group array by more than one property swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Swift provides a method that converts array to dictionary on the basis of single property. Is it possible to group array to dictionary on the basis of more than one property. Something like following

For example we have array of objects containing name, age and gender

```
Person{
  let name: String
  let age: Int
  let gender: String
}
```

And we have array containing persons

```
let array:[Person] = [Person(name: "Alex", age: 25, gender: "Male"), Person(name: "Sara", age: 25, gender: "Female")]
```

How can I group by multiple properties like name and age ?

```
Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0.name && $0.age })
```

Comment: added detail @matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group by anything that can become a key, in other words, by anything that is `Hashable`.

If you need to combine multiple properties, define a new type:

```
struct GroupingKey: Hashable {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
}

Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { GroupingKey(name: $0.name, age: $0.age) })
```